# How to get the inner table ignore the inherited styles

Tags: css

I have seen a few similar questions but they don't match what I am after. I have a situation where a table can have inner tables. However, I like the inner table to ignore the styles defined by "myTable". How can I do this?

Preferably, without adding a CSS for inner table. Or at least without adding a new class or reference to an ID for the inner table. Thank you for any help.

```css
        #myTable td, #myTable th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        #myTable th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #00bf11;
            color: white;
        }

        #myTable {
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            width: 100%; 
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-size: 12px; 
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)" style="width:6%;">Col1</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="width:9%;">Col2</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="width:85%;">Col3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Col One</th>
                      <th>Col Two</th>
                      <th>Col Three</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>One</td>
                      <td>Two</td>
                      <td>Three</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deryck has the right answer altough it's not complete because of browser implementation and missing `tr`

```css
#myTable > tbody > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#myTable > tbody > tr > th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #00bf11;
  color: white;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)" style="width:6%;">Col1</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="width:9%;">Col2</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="width:85%;">Col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Col One</th>
              <th>Col Two</th>
              <th>Col Three</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>One</td>
              <td>Two</td>
              <td>Three</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make it so the styles you have there don't apply to anything but the specific children (`tr`, `th`, etc at the top level) you can use `>` to specify the style to only apply to the direct children of `#myTable`

```css
        #myTable > td, #myTable > th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        #myTable > th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #00bf11;
            color: white;
        }

        #myTable {
            border-collapse: collapse; 
            width: 100%; 
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            font-size: 12px; 
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)" style="width:6%;">Col1</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(1)" style="width:9%;">Col2</th>
                <th onclick="sortTable(2)" style="width:85%;">Col3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Col One</th>
                      <th>Col Two</th>
                      <th>Col Three</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>One</td>
                      <td>Two</td>
                      <td>Three</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need the outer table of-course to retain its colors. If you run your solution it doesn't seem to work. :)

Comment: ``#myTable > tbody > tr > td`` and ``#myTable > tbody > tr > th`` works. It's because the browser adds a tbody element around the table content.